# Using object from different module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I've the following code which is parse object and and provide getters to it like following and this is working,The problem is that I want to access to this object from different module and avoid the parsing again ,how can I do that without define global var?

```
var ymlParser = require('yamljs');

function ymlParse(src) {
    if (!(this instanceof ymlParse)) return new ymlParse(src);
    this.data = ymlParser.parse(src);
}

ymlParse.prototype = {
    getA: function () {
        return this.data.default_A;
    },

    getB: function () {
        return this.data._B;
    }
};

module.exports = ymlParse;
```

Lets say I want to access to A from module A and B from module B,how can I do that without sending the **src** again when I call to  getB since when I call to getA I already pass the src...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Memoization pattern - http://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/. The one issue with implementation in others answers is not hashing the arguments. So you should have something like this:

```
var ymlParser = require('yamljs');

function ymlParse(src) {
  var hash = JSON.stringify(src);

  if (!(this instanceof ymlParse)) return new ymlParse(src);
  if (this.cache[hash]) {
    this.data = this.cache[hash];
  } else {
    this.data = ymlParser.parse(src);
    this.cache[hash] = this.data;
  }
}

ymlParse.prototype = {
  cache: {},

  getA: function () {
    return this.data.default_A;
  },

  getB: function () {
    return this.data._B;
  }
};

module.exports = ymlParse;
```

Take a closer look to JSON.stringify method. You must implement hashing algorithm here that will be associate hash with src data as unique identifier. Usually is JSON.stringify but you can use your own.

Or another solution in functional style:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var ymlParser = require('yamljs');

function ymlParse(src) {
  var result = ymlParser.parse(src);

  return {
    getA: function() {
      return result.default_A;
    },
    getB: function() {
      return result._B;
    }
  };
}

module.exports = _.memoize(ymlParse);
```

Usage the same, you just call exported function as usual function.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that when I call to A I pass the src and when I call to B I dont have the src to pass to it,there is a way to overcome it?

Comment: Sorry this is not working the cache is empty when I trying to get value from other module,but maybe I call it in wrong way,how should I call it for diffrent module assume that one is provide the src and second not?

Comment: How can you call the function if you don't have arguments ? You are doing something wrong so that try to solve this without splitting into modules.

Comment: With functional style for instance, you have function that can remember calculated results. If you call the function with src it remember it and store the result in cache. But how do you offer to do if you don't have src at all ?

Comment: Lets assume that I need to  parse just one file in my node app,so the first caller is called with the src and then the data is parsed and the others modules can get the properties they need without sending the src,..since the data already parsed and serve all the modules

Comment: I don't know what to say, sorry :) You have a memoized function so that can return result from cache if you provide the same arguments. If you can't grab src data from another module, you just need to make another function in your module that can get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make caching in your `ymlParse` class (it's designed like class, isn't it?).
Just store `src` objects and results of parsing. If `ymlParse` will be executed with cached `src` just return stored result without parsing.

Try to change your code like this:

```
var ymlParser = require('yamljs');

function ymlParse(src) {
    if (!(this instanceof ymlParse)) return new ymlParse(src);
    if (this.cache[src]) {
        this.data = this.cache[src];
    } else {
        this.data = ymlParser.parse(src);
        this.cache[src] = this.data;
    }
}

ymlParse.prototype = {
    cache: {},

    getA: function () {
        return this.data.default_A;
    },

    getB: function () {
        return this.data._B;
    }
};

module.exports = ymlParse;
```

Notice that I'm not using deep copy of `this.data` object. If it's not read-only it may cause some problems.

Comment: Thanks I try it but when I access from Module B the this.cache[src] is empty so the parse is called again...maybe I call this wrong? how should I call it(to the function) ?

Comment: Please remeber that I need to call it from two different modules

Comment: It's a bit strange. I'm not sure, but as far as I know every module executes only one time, on first require, other times it's just returns `module.exports` to others. So, basing on this, all your modules should have the same instance of `module.exports` of your parser and it's prototype.

Comment: Try to find out - is your module executes only one time or more. You can do this just by adding console.log in the beginning of it.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that when I call to A I pass the src and when I call to B I dont have the src to pass to it,there is a way to overcome it

Comment: Umm.. But if you have no src in B - what you want to parse? Or this function is used only ONE time? If it is, I can change the code above to match this requirement.

Comment: The parse should be done only one time...and it doesnt matter if from getA or getB the first caller should provide it...